# libtorrent how to get a list of files seed content?

Tags: python, libtorrent, torrent

```
import libtorrent as lt
import time
import sys

ses = lt.session()
ses.listen_on(6881, 6891)
params = {
    'save_path': '/home',
    'storage_mode': lt.storage_mode_t(2),
    'paused': False,
    'auto_managed': True,
    'duplicate_is_error': True
    }

link = "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:4fabfdfe37295ee2cb1ac2440f45e36ce022b209"
h = lt.add_magnet_uri(ses, link, params)

ses.add_dht_router("router.utorrent.com", 6881)
ses.add_dht_router("router.bittorrent.com", 6881)
ses.add_dht_router("dht.transmissionbt.com", 6881)
ses.start_dht()

while (not h.has_metadata()):
    time.sleep(.1)

torinfo = h.get_torrent_info()

print torinfo.name()
print torinfo.creation_date()
print torinfo.info_hash()
print lt.make_magnet_uri(torinfo)

for tracker in torinfo.trackers():
    print tracker

for x in torinfo.files():
    ???
```

About this torrent_info class document: http://libtorrent.org/reference-Core.html#torrent_info

Because I do not know C ++, Get to the list of seed files. use **Python**.

Comment: what do you mean by "list of seed files". you mean the list of files in the torrent?

Comment: Hi, would you help me please to run this code. in my case it stuck in the while loop.

Comment: @muaaz You need a callback to get the information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

torrent_info.files() returns [`file_storage`](http://libtorrent.org/reference-Storage.html#file_storage) object. This object represents the file layout in the torrent, including piece size and list of files. The `file_storage` object does not provide access to its internal list of files (to allow its representation to change without altering the ABI). Instead you can call `num_files()` to know how many files there are, and then ask for specific attributes of files given their index.

for instance `file_path(index)` or `file_size(index)`.